# TwiML play digits not recognized

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

We are trying to implement a twilio app that answers IVF interactively, so that we will save manual calling that IVF number.  We have got the gather work to get what the other side has been saying, but after "press 2" step, either that "2" is not recognized, or the phone will hang up.  Here is the code

```
response.gather({
  input: ['speech', 'dtmf'],
  speechTimeout: 'auto',
  action: '/webhook/twilio/interactive'
});

response.play({"digits":"w2w2w2"});
response.type('text/xml');
response.send(response.toString());
```

Comment: We tried both gather => play or play=> gather, both not recognized.